# Python Installation: Issues Adding Path Despite Manual Adjustment

Tags: python, windows, installation, path, environment-variables

I have installed Python on my computer and checked the box that includes the path during installation. However, the path was not automatically added, so I tried to manually add it, but it did not work. I have checked the path several times for typos or other errors, but could not find any.

I then installed a different version of Python and manually adjusted the path to refer to the new version, but it also did not work. I tried to change the Path in the System Variables, but that did not work either.

In collaboration with Chat GPT, we have tried various solutions including checking system variables and manually entering paths, but none of these approaches solved the problem.

I was expecting the path to be added automatically during installation, but when it wasn't, I tried to manually add it myself. I was also expecting changing the path in the system variables to work, but it didn't. I am still searching for a solution to this problem and would appreciate any help or suggestions that could help me successfully run Python on my computer.